# If a sequence $p_n$ converges to a point $p$ then every neighborhood of $p$ contains $p_n$ for all but finitely many n.

Tags: real-analysis

This is a theorem in Rudin. I proved it myself and the proof is different than Rudin and wanted to check that my proof was valid.
My proof:
Suppose $p_n$ converges to p(In a metric space X). Consider an arbitrary neighborhood around $p$, i.e. the points such that $d(p,q) < r$, where $q \in X$ and $r>0$. Since $p_n$ converges to $p$, we have that for some integer $N_r$, for every $n \geq N_r$, $d(p,p_n) < r$. This means that for the points $n \in (1,2,..., N_r -1)$, $p_n$ is not in the neighborhood of $p$. Since this set is clearly finite, and the neighborhood is arbitrary, the statement is proven.

Answer (score 1):

> for the points $n \in \{1, \ldots, N_r - 1\}$, $p_n$ is not in the neighborhood of $p$.

This is not true. It might be that some of these $p_n$ are in the neighborhood. Just because you know $p_n$ is in the neighborhood when $n \ge N_r$ does not say anything about $p_n$ when $n < N_r$.
That said, $p_n$ for $n \in \{1, \ldots, N_r-1\}$ *contains* all the $p_n$ that are not in the neighborhood of $p$, so indeed there are only finitely many of them.

Comment: ah that makes sense. thanks